# Expected ways to debug an async stack - what's going on?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have a method that inconsistently fails, therefore I can't replicate with any certainty.

I've captured the stacktrace and exception of one of these failures (below). Usually this would just be a case of exploring the stack to understand how the code got to it's current state.

However since the method is marked **async** the stack trace *makes no sense*.

I'd love to be able to check what the various variables were set to. Does anyone have any hints / tips / proven ways of working with an async stack so I can get the root of my issue?

[image: async stack trace]

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: can't you just debug it and follow your variable with breakpoints ?

Comment: I would do but it's occurs very infrequently during an automated test run - so I'd have to sit there for a long while watching the variable in each previous step hoping this is the time it fails

Comment: Can see the InnerException of your AggregateException for more data? Usually that's a good place to look.

Comment: @TeodorKurtev - Unfortunately it's null

Comment: @m.edmondson judging from the error you can just try to try and think about which variable may become null thus raising the error but i don't know the length of your code

Comment: Hmm, well you can try to Flatten the AggregateException and see what comes out: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Pictures of exceptions are incredibly unhelpful for a number of reasons.  Call ToString on it and paste that into an edit.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Async Diagnostics](https://nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncDiagnostics/) library together with PostSharp to get logical stack.  See the article [Async Diagnostics blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/announcement-async-diagnostics.html)

Comment: I've added this but get postsharp versioning problems - I'm a bit surprised something as important as this has only 1000 downloads.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is usually not usable in async code because it will just tell you that the call to some async method has fail.
Neither is the debug step by step, because if it is hard to reproduce, it is probably a timing error and you will never reproduce it in debug.

Instead use try/catch and check the aggregate exception. Be sure that your method return a Task, and that this Task is awaited, or you won't catch anything.

I think this [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you to catch your error correctly.